# spring security deleting users failure

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

I am running a 1.1.4.RELEASE spring-boot app using Spring security.  I have the basic Spring Users and Authorities table and entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "username", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Authorities> roles = new HashSet<Authorities>();

/// getters and setters
}


@Entity
public class Authorities {

    @Id
    private String username;
    private String authority;
    /// getters and setters
}
```

I have a repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

    User findUserByUsername(String username);

    void delete(String username);

    List<User> findAll();
}
```

That I use as:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser/{username}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String username, Model model) {
        customUserDetailsService.delete(username);

        **the following line throws the exception**
        model.addAttribute(UPLOAD, customUserDetailsService.findAllUsers());
        return "admin";
}
```

When I try and delete a user, I get an error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["IX_AUTH_USERNAME: PUBLIC.AUTHORITIES FOREIGN KEY(USERNAME) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USERS(USERNAME) ('testUser')"; SQL statement:
delete from USERS where username=? [23503-172]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I think my mapping is wrong, but honestly I don't see where.

**UPDATE**:
Based on the excellent feedback, I now have the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private String companyName;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="Authorities", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="username"))
    @Column(name="authority")
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();

// getters & setters
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

    User findUserByUsername(String username);

    void delete(String username);

    List<User> findAll();
}
```

which I use via:

```
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Admin')")
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser/{username}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String username, Model model) {
        customUserDetailsService.delete(username);
        updateModelWithAllUsers(model);
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "admin";
    }

    private void updateModelWithAllUsers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(USERLIST, customUserDetailsService.findAllUsers());
    }
..
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
   public void delete(String username) {
        userRepository.delete(username);
    }
..
}
```

I am using H2, which I create and seed in liquibase as:

```
<createTable tableName="Users">
    <column name="username" type="VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50)"/>
    <column name="password" type="VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(500)"/>
    <column name="companyName" type="VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(500)"/>
    <column name="enabled" type="boolean"/>
    <column name="accountNonExpired" type="boolean"/>
    <column name="accountNonLocked" type="boolean"/>
    <column name="credentialsNonExpired" type="boolean"/>
</createTable>

<createTable tableName="Authorities">
    <column name="username" type="VARCHAR(50)">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"
                     foreignKeyName="ix_auth_username" references="Users(username)" deleteCascade="true"/>
    </column>
    <column name="authority" type="VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(500)"/>
</createTable>
```

So this appears to work fine.  The edge condition is that if I create a user, delete and then create a user with the same username I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_A ON PUBLIC.AUTHORITIES(USERNAME)"; SQL statement:
insert into Authorities (username, authority) values (?, ?) [23505-172]
```

Comment: Did you try deleting the user's authorities first and then deleting the user?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also, but it throws a ReferentialIntegrityException or something.

Comment: To nail the problem, update question with implementation of `delete` and how you create the tables.

Comment: I have updated the question with my current code state.   Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know much about liquibase, but you seem to have mixed up primary key with foreign key. The primary key for authorities table must span over both username and authority. Otherwise a user can have only one role.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Authorities` class. Remember, entities are not the same as tables. Use the following mapping in User class:

```java
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="authorities", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="username"))
@Column(name="authority")
private Set<String> authorities;
```

Additionally, you can add `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign key.

Comment: Not sure I follow.   If I don't have the entity, how do I persist Authorities for users like:  **bold**Authorities authorities = new Authorities(user.getUsername(), "USER");      user.getRoles().add(authorities); **bold** If I do add authorities as Strings, do those get persisted?

Comment: Yes, they will be persisted when the User object is persisted.

Comment: What do I need to do to delete the authorities with the user?  I made your suggestions above and added a constraint to the username column to deleteCascade="true".  but when I delete a user, I don't think the authorities is being deleted as well (its H2 so I can' visually verify the record).

Comment: The related rows in authorities table should automatically be deleted when you delete the user. With the foreign key in place (looks like it in your question), don't worry.

Comment: If I create a user, then delete it, and try to recreate the same username I get the exception:   **bold**could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY_KEY_A ON PUBLIC.AUTHORITIES(USERNAME)"; SQL statement: insert into Authorities (username, authority) values (?, ?) [23505-172]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute stateme **bold**   So I think the Authorities table record is not being properly deleted